# Hiding User Info on a Discussion Board

Tags: sharepoint-online, discussion-board

We have a discussion board on SharePoint where we would like to prevent a general user from seeing who submitted or replied to a post. I have not been able to find a way to modify the view to remove the user information. I did change the display to show the user's department instead but when you hover over it, the user's name is displayed.

To clarify, we do not want to enable anonymous users on the site as it is secured. I'm mainly looking for the code that I can enter in a script editor web part to hide the information. Our company also has SharePoint Designer and InfoPath disabled.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add the following CSS style into a Script Editor Web Part in AllItem.aspx page.

```
<style type="text/css">
ul.ms-comm-metalineList.ms-noList>li.ms-comm-metalineItemSeparator.ms-comm-metalineItem{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

Add the following CSS style into a Script Editor Web Part in Flat.aspx page.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-comm-authorPicture{
    display:none;
}
.ms-comm-authorTitle{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing! @LZ_MSFT